# Is a bijective morphism between affine varieties an isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, morphism, closed-map

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $X,Y$ affine varieties (both irreducible) and a morphism $f:X\to Y$. The pullback $f^*:A(Y)\to A(X)$ is surjective $\Leftrightarrow$ $f$ is injective and $f(X)\subset Y$ is closed.

[*correction: as shown in* @MooS's *answer, the statement above is false*]

I was able to prove $(\Rightarrow)$ by observing that $A(\overline{f(X)})\simeq A(Y)/\ker(f^*)\simeq \text{im}(f^*)=A(X)$, so that $f$ gives an isomorphism between $X$ and $\overline{f(X)}$, so it must be injective and $f(X)=\overline{f(X)}$.

Now I'm having trouble proving $(\Leftarrow)$. If $f$ is injective and $f(X)=Y$ is closed, $f:X\to f(X)$ is a bijective morphism between affine varieties. It seems to me (I might be wrong) that in order to prove $f^*$ is surjective I should prove $f$ is an isorphism, but I can't see how to do that.

Is there a better way?

Comment: An affine variety is always reduced in your case?

Comment: Certainly a bijective morphism of (reduced) varieties need not be an isomorphism; the classic example is $t\mapsto (t^2,t^3)$, a bijection between $\mathbf A^1$ and a cuspidal cubic.

Comment: @MooS yes, I've implicitly assumed they are irreducible

Comment: @JohnBrevik you're totally right. Then how could I prove $f^*$ is surjective?

Comment: You cannot, since it is false.

Answer (score 1):

$f:\mathbb A^1 \to V(x^3-y^2), t \mapsto (t^2,t^3)$ is bijective, in particular it is injective with closed image, but $f^*: \mathbb C[x,y] \to \mathbb C[t], x \mapsto t^2, y \mapsto t^3$ is not surjective, since the image is $\mathbb C[t^2,t^2] \subsetneq \mathbb C[t]$.

Comment: That's right, I've just realized that. I should correct the statement to "$\Leftrightarrow f(X)\subset Y$ is closed and $f:X\to f(X)$ is an isomorphism", would you agree?

Comment: Then it is correct, because this yields that in the composition $X \to f(X) \hookrightarrow Y$, the pullbacks of both arrows are surjective, in particular the whole pullback is surjective as a composition of two surjections.